# Multidimensional Array - creating a table

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a table of all the zodiac symbols with their years underneath (12 columns, n rows, dates range from 1912 to 2013) using multidimensional arrays.

I have my code below and that's where I'm completely stuck.

My code:

```
<script>
    // declaring a 2D array
    var signs = new Array(12);
    for (var ndx = 0; ndx < 12; ndx++) {
        signs[ndx] = new Array(2);
    }

    // The names first
    signs[0][0] = "Rat";
    signs[1][0] = "Ox";
    signs[2][0] = "Tiger";
    signs[3][0] = "Rabbit";
    signs[4][0] = "Dragon";
    signs[5][0] = "Snake";
    signs[6][0] = "Horse";
    signs[7][0] = "Goat";
    signs[8][0] = "Monkey";
    signs[9][0] = "Rooster";
    signs[10][0] = "Dog";
    signs[11][0] = "Pig";

    // Next the image file names
    signs[0][1] = "rat.gif";
    signs[1][1] = "ox.gif";
    signs[2][1] = "tgr.gif";
    signs[3][1] = "rbt.png";
    signs[4][1] = "drgn.png";
    signs[5][1] = "snk.png";
    signs[6][1] = "hrs.gif";
    signs[7][1] = "gt.gif";
    signs[8][1] = "mnky.png";
    signs[9][1] = "rstr.gif";
    signs[10][1] = "dog.gif";
    signs[11][1] = "pig.gif";

    document.write("<h2>");
    document.write("</h2>");

    document.writeln("<table border= '0' width = '100%'>");
    document.writeln("<tr>");


    for (var i = 0; i < SignNames.length; i++) {
        document.writeln("<td>");
        document.writeln(SignNames[i] + "<br />");
        document.writeln("<img src='Images/" + SignImages[i] + "'/>");
        document.writeln("</td>");
    }
    document.writeln("</tr>");

    document.writeln("<tr>");
    for (var i = 1912; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
        document.writeln("<td>" + i + "</td>");

        tableCols++;
        if (tableCols == 12) {
            tableCols = 0;
            document.writeln("</tr>");
        }
    }

    document.writeln("</table>");
</script>
```

Comment: What's your exact problem?

Comment: Why you stuck? Please describe

Comment: How do I get the signs [0][01] etc to show up in table rows.  I want the name and picture each in a top cell, with the years associated in the column below

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that, Terry

Comment: It's been solved.  Thanks to everybody who helped! (I'm new to learning Javascript and Java, so I'm easily confused and make lots of silly errors)

Comment: @nnnnnn My apologies, I was too stupid to scroll down through all that he posted. Another senior moment for me, I fear. Thank you for your message.

Comment: @Terry - No problem, we've all done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious problem in your code is that you declare an array called `signs` and then later in your for loop try to access it as `SignNames`. You need to match up the variable names. You're also using a variable `tableCols` that is never declared and initialised. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
document.writeln("<table border= '0' width = '100%'>");
document.writeln("<tr>");

for (var i = 0; i < signs.length; i++) {
    document.writeln("<td>");
    document.writeln(signs[i][0] + "<br />");
    document.writeln("<img src='Images/" + signs[i][1] + "'/>");
    document.writeln("</td>");
}
document.writeln("</tr>");

document.writeln("<tr>");
var tableCols = 0; // <---- this variable wasn't initialised in your code
for (var i = 1912, d = new Date().getFullYear(); i <= d; i++) {        
    document.writeln("<td>" + i + "</td>");
    if (++tableCols == 12) {
        tableCols = 0;
        document.writeln("</tr>");
    }
}
document.writeln("</table>");
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/IZUnoSu/1/edit

Also your array initialisation is more complicated than necessary. You don't need to use `new Array(12)` to create an array with 12 elements, you can just declare an empty array with `signs = []` and then start adding to it. But even that is more complicated than you need because you can declare the whole thing in a single statement with a nested array literal:

```
var signs = [
      ["Rat","rat.gif"],
      ["Ox","ox.gif"],
      ["Tiger","tgr.gif"],
      ["Rabbit","rbt.png"],
      ["Dragon","drgn.png"],
      ["Snake","snk.png"],
      ["Horse","hrs.gif"],
      ["Goat","gt.gif"],
      ["Monkey","mnky.png"],
      ["Rooster","rstr.gif"],
      ["Dog","dog.gif"],
      ["Pig","pig.gif"]
    ];
```

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure what I was doing with those names there.  I see I wasn't terribly far off from completing it though.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if you open your browser's console (ctrl-shift-J in Chrome, or - from memory - ctrl-shift-K in FF) then JavaScript errors are reported for you and you would've seen `Uncaught ReferenceError: SignNames is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd prefer if you defined your data like this:

```
var signs = [
  { name: "rat", image: "rat.gif" },
  { name: "ox", image: "ox.gif" },
  ...
  { name: "pig", image: "pig.gif" } // note: no trailing comma here
};
```

Then you can write `signs[0].name` to access the name. That's easier to read.

Now the only thing left to fix is that you replace `SignNames` with `signs`, since that's the name of your array.